# Persistência de DateTime AngularJS x Java x MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs, hibernate, jpa

Criei um aplicativo em nossa empresa para controlar o uso de certos equipamentos de nossa Industria. O fato é que surgiu a necessidade de controlar data/hora de entrada e saída de um produto em um certo equipamento.

Minha arquitetura: Front: HTML + Angular JS / Back: Java (JPA / REST) + Banco MySQL

O código HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4"><label>Data Final</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" ng-model="lancamento.dataFinal" required>
</div>
```

No Java, criei a classe lançamentos com o atributo `dataInicial` ( `private LocalDateTime dataInicial;` ) e os get/sets ...

No LOG do WildFly ele da a mensagem:

> Erro: Status:400 Mensagem:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.time.LocalDateTime]
>   from String value ('2016-10-06T14:22:00.000Z'); no single-String
>   constructor/factory method at [Source:
>   io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl@13718c2; line: 1,
>   column: 25] (through reference chain:
>   com.controlequalidade.vo.Lancamentos["dataInicial"])

Eu tentei utilizar outros formatos de data, converter tudo em String para o Java, e ali instanciar um objeto de data e jogar no banco, mas nenhuma opção foi aceita. No MySQL o tipo da coluna está como TIMESTAMP.

Em anexo segue o Front (HTML > Controller > Service) e a classe `Lancamentos` do Java.

Comment: Qual versão do Jackson está usando? Até onde sei as versões recentes convertem automaticamente o `LocalDateTime`. O problema é que ele não está conseguindo converter um objeto desse tipo em `String`. Se estiver usando uma versão antiga, terá que implementar a interface `JsonSerializer` e especificar como deve ser a conversão do objeto para string.

Comment: Bom dia Renan! Estou utilizando a versão 2.8.1 do Jackson. Nunca usei nada relacionado a serialização de JSON...